# How to disable RichTextBox color/size changing property?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

For example, when I copy three lines of code (from VS) and paste it directly into my RichTextBox, the font/size/color will be deformed (for example "End sub" color will be turned into blue). Is there any way to disable this property?

Comment: WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms, and since RichTextBox does not have a default context menu, you'll probably have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the contents. In which case, you can use the `KeyDown` event to handle how the text is pasted. Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
    If (e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V) Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart,
                                                     Clipboard.GetText())
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: You may also capture the less-used combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> if you wish to:

```
If (e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V) OrElse (e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Insert) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The Text Editor colors and font styles can be pesonalized using the Options tool:

**`Tools => Option => Fonts and Colors => Text Editor (ComboBox selection)`**

These style define the text presented in the Code Editor.

The Copy and Printing styles are defined using the **`Printer and Cut/Copy`** set:

**`Tools => Option => Fonts and Colors => Printer and Cut/Copy`**

**This applies to both WinForms and WPF** (these settings are shared).

[image: Visual Studio Options personalize font and colors]

Not all styles are included in the RTF text pasted in a control.
Set the **`Item backgroung`** to **`Automatic`** to match the target Control BackColor  setting.

A thoughtfull personalization of some styles. The code is pasted in a RichTextBox control.
The font is set to TimesNew Roman in the Options tool.
(You need to copy again the code, if you change the styles, to apply the new settings)

[image: Visual Studio Options personalize font and colors]

Comment: I think the OP used copying text from VS just as an example. A formatted text could come from anywhere else.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed   Well, maybe. The OP wrote *(...) when I copy three lines of code(...)* and *"End sub" color will be turned into blue*. It seems quite specific. The OP will tell us what the actual intentions are, eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but VS syntax was just an example (as stated at the start of my question), for better understanding take a look at this [link](https://imgur.com/a/uQ2UugD) and then this [link](https://imgur.com/JOctprf) . (the first one is pasted after pasting it somewhere else and the second one is pasted directly into rtb) It will be solved **only** if I copy the code and paste it somewhere else.

Comment: Do you want to copy/paste code from Visual Studio or not? Any generic source? You need to be explicit when you describe what you're looking for. Of course, if you copy code from VS and paste it in, say, Notepad, then copy/paste it back, any color setting will be lost. What are you actually trying to do? If you want to copy/paste code from VS and have a single color, set all color option s to the same color. That's one possibility. Or copy back plain text, +- what Ahmed Abdelhameed is showing.

Comment: Do you want to **preserve**, do you want to **lose** or do you want to **customize** the color/font settings that come with the text?

Comment: Ahmed's code didn't worked at first but after a little bit changing it, it's working.I wanted to remove the color and that method is working fine, thanks for spending your time @Jimi

Comment: Well, sure. What matters is that the question is answered :)